# How to print the value of the last \refstepcounter in the first page in the memoir class?

Tags: environments, memoir, counters

I made an environment named `sol`, that has a `\refstepcounter` command. I want to print on the first page of my document how many `sol` environments I have made in my document.

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,11pt,twocolumn,openany,openbib]{memoir}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcounter{sol}

\newenvironment{sol}[2]%
{\refstepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}%
\centering\textsc{\Large\textbf{#1}}\\%
\noindent By: \textbf{#2}\\%    
\begin{raggedright}\ignorespaces}%
{\end{raggedright}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
This document consists of \thesol\ sols.
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn
.
.
.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

However, the value of the `sol` counter in the first page I always get is 0, since the there is no preceding `sol` environment from the `\thesol` command. So I came up, with the following solution:

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,11pt,twocolumn,openany,openbib]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcounter{sol}
\addtocounter{sol}{-1}

\newenvironment{sol}[2]%
{\refstepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}%
\centering\textsc{\Large\textbf{#1}}\\%
\noindent By: \textbf{#2}\\%    
\begin{raggedright}\ignorespaces}%
{\end{raggedright}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
This document consists of \ref{sol:num}\ sols.
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn
.
.
.
{\color{white}
\begin{sol}{\color{white}a}{\color{white}a}
\label{sol:num}
\end{sol}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

However, the new problem that arises is that the output of the code `\color{white}a` appears in the ToC and in the Index, as specified by the `sol` environment. 
**Note:** I placed the second issue in the same thread because I think the first one is not attainable, based on my present knowledge regarding `LaTeX`.

Comment: The whole \ref \label \refstepcounter system (which includes the toc) works by writing data into a file which is read the next time LaTeX runs.  However, what it stores depends on things like \@currentlabel so that it knows whether to store equation, references, chapters, etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks, but what can I do to print those stored values?

Comment: @Acnologia: The title of your question is a bit misleading: You mean the last `\refstepcounter` of `sol` counter and not the very last call to `\refstepcounter` of any counter in the document.

Comment: Yes, @ChristianHupfer. I think I am referring to the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `totcount` has exactly this purpose:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{totcount}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcounter{sol}
\regtotcounter{sol}

\newenvironment{sol}[2]
  {\refstepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
   \centering{\Large\scshape #1\\}
   \raggedright
   By: \textbf{#2}\\
   \ignorespaces}
  {\par}

\begin{document}
This document consists of \total{sol} sols.

\begin{sol}{Abc}{Def}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{sol}

Another

\begin{sol}{Abc}{Def}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was the simplest solution I have ever tumbled on regarding this problem. In the first run, I have encountered no errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: Use the `LastPage` trick for another counter:

Write the value of the `sol` counter to the `.aux` file at the end of the document and rerun (which is to be done basically always) `pdflatex` (or `latex`) -- it reads the number stored in `TotalSolEnvs` and can be output wherever needed.

The `\AtEndDocument` command executes commands at the end of the document, so the command `\WriteNumberOfSolEnvs` too, being responsible for storing the number of used solution environments.

This mechanism works for other counters too.

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,11pt,twocolumn,openany,openbib]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcounter{sol}

\newcounter{TotalSolEnvs}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WriteNumberOfSolEnvs}{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \string\setcounter{TotalSolEnvs}{\number\value{sol}}
}
}
\makeatother


\AtEndDocument{%
  \WriteNumberOfSolEnvs%
}%

\newenvironment{sol}[2]%
{\refstepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}%
\centering\textsc{\Large\textbf{#1}}\\%
\noindent By: \textbf{#2}\\%    
\begin{raggedright}\ignorespaces}%
{\end{raggedright}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
This document consists of \number\value{TotalSolEnvs}~ sols.
\tableofcontents
\twocolumn
\begin{sol}{Arg1}{Arg2}%
\end{sol}

\begin{sol}{Arg1}{Arg2}%
\end{sol}

\begin{sol}{Arg1}{Arg2}%

\end{sol}

\begin{sol}{Arg1}{Arg2}%
\end{sol}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked for me! This is what I'm thinking to do, to deceive my LaTeX code that that part is the last page, but I can't do. However, I suggest @ChristianHupfer to simplify `\number\value{TotalSolEnvs}` to `\theTotalSolEnvs`. The `\the<counter>` command gives the numerical value of a counter. I tested my suggestion and it worked!

Comment: @Acnologia: Well, there is one little caveat: As soon as `\theTotalSolEnvs` is redefined to output the counter number (and not the numerical value!!!) in Roman or in upcase/lowcase letters, you will get `I` or `F` for example but not `1` or `6` respectively. `\number\value{TotalSolEnvs}` however will give you the numerical value ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,11pt,twocolumn,openany,openbib]{memoir}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter% I stole this, more or less, from hyperref
\def\total{%
  \@bsphack
  \begingroup
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{total}{%
        {}% not used
        {\thepage}%
        {}% not used
        {\arabic{sol}}{}%
      }%
    }%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}%
\makeatother

\newcounter{sol}

\newenvironment{sol}[2]%
{\stepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}%
\centering\textsc{\Large\textbf{#1}}\\%
\noindent By: \textbf{#2}\\%    
\begin{raggedright}\ignorespaces}%
{\end{raggedright}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
This document consists of \ref{total} sols.
\tableofcontents

\begin{sol}{First}{Golly}
Body of text.
\end{sol}

\begin{sol}{Second}{Gosh}
More text.
\end{sol}

\total
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I obtained errors from building this code, which both say that `total` is an undefined reference. I tried replacing `\total` with `\label{total}` but the error still persisted (after building thrice).

Comment: Haha, ok, disregard my previous comment. I worked on the code again and it produced a pdf file, but the code `This document consists of \ref{total} sols.` resulted to **This document consists of 5 sols.** I think it is due to `\setcounter{sol}{5}` macro.

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to get 0 sols and was in a hurry.  I will correct it.

Comment: BTW, you can use \stepcounter instead of \refstepcounter.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand{\manuallabel}[2]{\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}}
\newcounter{sol}
\addtocounter{sol}{0}

\newenvironment{sol}[2]%
{\refstepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}%
\centering\textsc{\Large\textbf{#1}}\\%
\noindent By: \textbf{#2}\\%    
}
```

and this to the end of your document:

```
\manuallabel{counter}{\number\numexpr\getrefnumber{solref@\number\value{sol}}}
```

Now you can use

```
This document consists of \ref{counter} sols.

\sol{1}{2}
```

You can use different names by changing the following two lines:

```
\manuallabel{NAME}{...
This document consists of \ref{NAME} sols.
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,11pt,twocolumn,openany,openbib]{memoir}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand{\manuallabel}[2]{\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}}
\newcounter{sol}
\addtocounter{sol}{0}

\newenvironment{sol}[2]%
{\refstepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}%
\centering\textsc{\Large\textbf{#1}}\\%
\noindent By: \textbf{#2}\\%    
}

\begin{document}
This document consists of \ref{counter} sols.
\tableofcontents

\sol{1}{1}
\sol{1}{1}

\manuallabel{counter}{\number\numexpr\getrefnumber{solref@\number\value{sol}}}
\end{document}
```

> This document consists of 2 sols.

Comment: Typing this code:
`This document consists of \thesol\ sols.`
Still results to: **This document consists of 0 sols.**

Comment: Oh sorry, you have to use This document consists of \ref{counter} sols. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I implemented the change you suggested in the code. But it resulted to **This document consists of  sols.** Another thing, do I really need to add `\addtocounter{sol}{0}`? As far as I know, its purpose is only to add 0 to `sol` counter.

Comment: No, you don't need to add this line but you can start with different values.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think you have turned `sol` into a command, but I need it to be an environment.