# How to make some visible effect on the output file of a document "invisible" or non-effective while fulfilling its "invisible" function?

Tags: environments, counters

Are there any commands/packages/environments that can make some code that has a visible effect in the output file as if it were not written but fulfilling its internal function?
For example,

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcounter{sol}
\addtocounter{\thesol}{-1}
\newenvironment{sol}[2]%
{\refstepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}%
\centering\textsc{\Large\textbf{#1}}\\%
\noindent By: \textbf{#2}\\%    
\begin{raggedright}\ignorespaces}%
{\end{raggedright}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
This document shows \ref{sol:num} sols.
.
\begin{sol}{}{}
\label{sol:num}
\end{sol}
.
\end{document}
```

In the code above, the last `sol` environment serves to count all the existing `sol` environments in the document other than itself (shown by adding -1 to the counter) by labeling and referring. However, the `sol` environment provides visible effect in the output file like printing the characters `By:` and providing ToC and Index entries as we can see in its definition.

Comment: Did you mean to write `\addtocounter{sol}{-1}` instead of `\addtocounter{\thesol}{-1}`? Separately, would you mind clarifying what you mean by "make some code that has a visible effect in the output file as if it were not written but fulfilling its internal function"? Incidentally, your code is not easy to parse, in part because you use `sol` both as a counter and as an environment.

Comment: I believe this a follow up of your question about the `refstepcounter` of `sol` -- you do not need an additional call to the `sol` environment causing visual output. See the answers to your other question.

Comment: Please give some feedback as to whether or not [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180305/5764) is of any use to you. It may have to be moved to [your earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180284/5764)...

Comment: @Werner, sorry for asking such blurred question. At that time, I was thinking of 2 solutions for my problem, that is (a) making the visible output "invisible" and (b) counting the `sol` environments in the whole code. The second question was actually the follow-up one, as I think that, in my present scope of my knowledge, this is more possible than the other one. I think it's better to move your answer to the other question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180293/49303).

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be only interested in counting the number of `sol`s. For that, a package already exists that provides this functionality: [`totcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/totcount)

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{sol}% Register sol as a "total" counter
\newenvironment{sol}[2]%
  {\refstepcounter{sol}\index{\textbf{#2}}%
   \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect #1}%
   {\centering\Large\bfseries #1\par}%
   \noindent By: \textbf{#2}\par%    
   \begin{raggedright}\ignorespaces}%
  {\end{raggedright}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
This document shows \total{sol} sols.

\begin{sol}{First}{Second}
  Another solution
\end{sol}

\end{document}
```

Of course, if you want to remove one from this count (in order to exclude the last one), then do exactly as you've done before, by setting `\addtocounter{sol}{-1}` just after creating the counter.

If this doesn't work for you, for whatever reason, an alternative approach might be to hook into `\AtDocumentEnd`. Since you'll only be using the reference for counting purposes, this should be sufficient:

```
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thesol}% Store the value (representation) of sol
  \label{sol:num}% Mark with a label
}
\makeatother
```

This allows you to use `\ref{sol:num}` in your document that would show the total number of `sol`s. Of course, if you wish to exclude the last one, you can follow the same procedure as suggested above.

With both techniques you need to compile twice on the first go for references to settle. This also holds for any changes in the reference values.

Comment: You basically answered the OP's other question to be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180284/how-to-print-the-value-of-the-last-refstepcounter-in-the-first-page-in-the-memo/180293#180293 ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: What the... ?